# How to access an external SMTP server from Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, smtp

I'm trying to send an email from a python script in a kubernetes pod.
The smtp server is listening with the port 2525
but the script is sending from to port 25
I'm trying to make redirection

I created a service and an endpoint in the kubernetes cluster with this Yaml file:

````
```
```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: mailings
    namespace: spaceone
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 25
      targetPort: 2525


apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mailings
  namespace: spaceone
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 172.17.100.101
  ports:
    - port: 2525

```
```
````

This doesn't work

Please can you help  to Receive in  my mailbox the email sent from the python script

Comment: The smtp server is running outside of the cluster? Is there any error message? Can you reach the smtp server directly (by using its IP) from a pod inside of the cluster with telnet or netcat on port 2525? The formatting looks a bit broken, but still shoud be valid YAML.

Comment: Telnet 172.17.100.101 2525 works from the kubernetes machine
but ping 172.17.100.101 doesn't wok from the pod where is the script

Comment: The smtp server is running outside of the cluster